# Comparing current date with Date.Now() consideres current date as PAST

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have made a code which should validate that a chosen date is not in the past. I have use a DateTimePicker to select the date. The code is

```
' Validate Date Received
If DateTimePicker1.Text <= Date.Now() Then

    msg += "Enter a valid Date" & vbCr

End If
```

However if I choose the current date then the msg pops up as if the date is from the past.

I'm using VB.NET and I have a connection to an Access database.

Comment: In fact im probably using VB6, sorry someone allready told me i theres a difference and im not sure which one. += works for the msg part meaning its probably not VBA.

Comment: @HansUp As the question been updated? Where did he say he was using VBA?

Comment: @Jay The question was originally tagged with both vba and access-vba, and no vb.net tag.  You can check the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35946000/revisions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your datetimepicker letting the user select a date and a time, or just a date?

If it's just a date, then the time portion of the DateTime object will be 0, i.e. midnight. now() returns the date with the current time, which will normally be later than midnight.

Try comparing to today() instead of now().

Comment: If youve read my previous comments, please ignore. I've noticed my logic was wrong, changing Now to Today did solve the problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As @HansUp said - `+=` isn't in VBA and neithers `Date.Now()`.
`Now()` will return the date and time so the time will generally be later than the midnight selected in `DateTimePicker1` and I don't think the value in the text box will be treated as a date, just as text.

Try something along the lines of:

```
CDate(Forms("Form1").Controls("DateTimePicker1").Text) = Date
```

On the other hand, if you're using VB.Net my code probably won't work.

Comment: I think im using VB6, definitely not VB.NET. Where do i put this line of code into? And are you sure speech marks are ment to be around form1 and DateTimePicker1?

Comment: I have a separate validating method which is used when i click a button on the form to save the record. If the validating was succesful then the information gets saved. So where should i put this code in?

Comment: @KamilLazarowicz -  *"definitely not VB.NET"* - Are you sure about that? The code you've provided looks an awful lot like VB.NET code to me.

Comment: Well, it might be. I am using the visual basic that comes with visual studio. It work on .NET Microfost...   Framework

Comment: Yes you are dealing with an idiot here sorry for that, Just got a project due in very soon and i wont this out the way as quick as possible